# How can I use my webcam inside an Azure windows server virtual machine?

Tags: azure, augmented-reality, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows server 2016 vm on Azure and I am trying to do some work in Augmented Reality using Vuforia and Unity. An essential part of this is being able to use my webcam but once I am inside the VM it doesnt recognise my integrated webcam. I tried to connect a webcam through USB as well but this doesn't work either. Is this an impossible task...getting a server instance to recognise webcams on my laptop or is it actually possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve it by group policy. I have a similar test in my VM.

For Azure VM: install RDSH role, and edit local group policy following this path: **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection** , disable the setting of policy **Do not allow supported Plug and Play device redirection**.

For a Local win10 client: edit the local group policy from the path: **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client\RemoteFX USB Device Redirection**, enable the setting of policy **Allow RDP redirection of other supported RemoteFX USB devices from this computer**.

restart both sides to update the group policy.

Type the **mstsc** to launch the Remote Desktop connection, select related remotefx webcam from the path: Show Options-Local Resources-more under the local devices and resources. Then click ok, it should be work.