# How do I get a camera to work on an Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, camera, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I want to be able to use a camera on an Azure Virtual Machine using Windows 10.

Camera feed can either come through on local machine or a feed from another machine. Either way I get the below error:
We can't find your camera, NoCamerasAreAttached.

Even though I have enabled both through the connection and enable USB Redirection in Windows 10. incl gpedit.msc

Comment: Suggesting you to check this link and see if it help, revert for any help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698027/how-can-i-use-my-webcam-inside-an-azure-windows-server-virtual-machine

Answer (score 3):

the easiest solution I discovered is that you can go to the settings of Remote desktop connection in the **general** tab, go to the **connection setting** and select your RDP file of azure VM:
[image: general Rdp file]

**Second**, in the RDP setting go to the **local resource** and then go to the local device tab in setting and click on the **'more'** button:

[image: local resource image]

Enable both **checkpoints** inside the video catalog that include the webcam option:
[image]

**goog luck! hope it saves your day!**
@syedasadrazadevops

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have enabled devices redirection in the Remote Desktop connection via `MSTSC`. And check if you have enabled USB Redirection in both sides of the client and VM via `GPEDIT`. For more details, Refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698027/how-can-i-use-my-webcam-inside-an-azure-windows-server-virtual-machine).