# Azure Virtual machine camera

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to enable the camera on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine (Window 10)? if it is possible, can someone guide me with the procedure?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Then edit your question to be on-topic and include details so that an answer can be created. Show what you have tried and the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your local machine/laptop camera in azure VM

- Open MSTSC
- Go to show options
- Go to local resources and then go to more option in local drives and resources and select video capture devices and then login to the vm and access camera inside azure

[image]

[reference thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698027/how-can-i-use-my-webcam-inside-an-azure-windows-server-virtual-machine)